# Is my BTC gone?

Tags: lost-bitcoins

I sent 1 BTC back in 2014 to an exchange, I do not rember which Exchange I sent it to after the original transaction.

Is there a way for me to track down which exchange I sent it to? Willing to give a reward for anyone who helps me.

Comment: Do you still have the wallet you sent it from?  If so, look at the tx that you sent, and look up the address you sent it to.

Comment: I sent it from my coin base account.

Comment: I found the address I sent it to on there.

Comment: No - There is no way to track it down. All addresses are generated by using various private keys, especially on exchanges can even be multiple wallets.. There is no way to work out what address belongs to whom..... Because that was the whole point of Crypto Currencies.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess would be to track the exchange account:

1. find which major exchanges were running in 2014
2. Search your email accounts for messages sent from that domain or with the name in the subject line (assuming you signed up with email)
3. Got to the Exchange (assuming it's still operating) and recover you password or username
4. Rinse and repeat to all the exchanges you find on your email.
5. If the exchange is legit, I would imagine it's still there, or maybe there is records of its movement.

Recently I had to go back to 3 dormant accounts looking for forgotten bitcoins from back in the day. MtGox will forever be the ones that got away... but I learned my lesson.

I don't think you would have any luck looking via the public key.

Good luck!

If it helps, let's see that reward! If not, it was a nice incentive either way!

BTC - 
1EtFeNUW63tV1VsE6qsMqQzdDrV1mVLocL

LTC -
LV65oSDjcUoE7jbxoawG6KjBsP36eVPsTB

:)